# Writing 4 arguments with the write function to a file

Tags: python

I would like to write this to a file `f.write("add unit at-wc 0 0 0 %s" % x ,y, z, "0.000 0.000 0.000 ")` but when I do that I get an error saying `function takes exactly 1 argument (4 given).`

Comment: What is x, y, z? What output do you expect?

Comment: they are user inputs to the program

Comment: OK, say they are 1, 2 and 3. What do you want to see in the file?

Comment: I would expect 1.000 2.000 3.000

Comment: That is "add unit at-wc 1.000 2.000 3.000" or do you also want those zeros?

Comment: You'd make your errors easier to debug if you formatted your string on a separate line. This is true in most languages, while it's nice to have programs with low line counts, it's even nicer to see that your string formatting was incorrect and not suspect that the call to write was even involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the `%` operator incorrectly. You might be looking for something like this:

```
f.write("add unit at-wc 0 0 0 %s %s %s 0.000 0.000 0.000 " % (x, y, z))
```

Notice that the substitution variables `x, y, z` are all in parentheses, which means they are a single *tuple* passed to the `%` operator.

In your code, notice how you have *four* parameters to the `write()` function (I've put each parameter on a separate line to make it easier to see):

```
f.write(
    "add unit at-wc 0 0 0 %s" % x,
    y,
    z,
    "0.000 0.000 0.000 "
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`%` has higher precedence than `,`.

```
f.write("add unit at-wc 0 0 0 %s" % (x, y, z, "0.000 0.000 0.000 "))
```

But now you'll get a different error since you have more values than placeholders.